# Bitrix24 и Кэширование средствами php

Tags: php, битрикс24

Возможно ли совместить скрипты `Bitrix` и php-скрипт таким образом:

Нужно при обращении к конечной html-странице `page.html` из браузера (или не из браузера - безразлично) проверять, есть ли страница `page.html` в специально созданной папке cache.

Если есть, то отдавать ее из папки `cache`.
Если нет, то генерировать ее средствами `Bitrix`, создавать копию конечного html-файла и сохранять эту копию в папку `cache`.

При следующем обращении, соответственно, на первом шаге (проверка наличия `page.html` в папке `cache`) отдавать ее уже из кэша.

Без cms на это требуется 3-5 строк кода на `php`.
Но сайт, на котором это нужно сделать, написан на Битрикс24.
Можно ли совместить cms и php-скрипт для решения описанной задачи?

Насколько это трудоемко?
Спасибо!

P.S. Речь, конечно, идет не об одной странице, а о тысячах. Но для примера я про одну написала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Bitrix` есть класс `CPageCache`, должен подойти под вашу задачу.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cpagecache/startdatacache.php)

> Можно ли совместить cms и php-скрипт для решения описанной задачи?

да конечно, возможно строчек выйдет больше 3-5, тут уже от проекта зависит.